# "in danger": an adverb or an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Is the expression "in danger" an adverb or an adjective? Why?

Comment: Are you confusing this phrase with the verb _endanger_?

Comment: Well, it's a prepositional phrase, but whether it is used as an adverb or an adjective depends entirely on context— it is not innately one or the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is neither: it is a preposition phrase with (figurative) locative sense, usually  followed by a preposition phrase with *of* defining the danger.

> ... in danger of contracting the virus
>   ... in danger of being fired

The *of* phrase may be omitted when it is recoverable from context.

> John has been exposed to the virus. He is in danger.

You will probably find it deployed most often as a *predicate complement* to the verb *be*, with adjectival sense modifying the subject:

> John is in danger [of contracting the virus].

But it may also be deployed as an attributive adjectival. It will usually (and always when it is accompanied by the *of* phrase) be set after the noun or pronoun it modifies:

> People/those in danger of contracting the virus are monitored closely.

If the *of* phrase is omitted *in danger* may be set before the noun modified; in this case it is a courtesy to readers to hyphenate it.

> We monitor in-danger children particularly closely.